# How to cast from an object[] stored as object in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have a `List<object>` stored in a database.
Each list object consists of an `object[]` consisting of int values.

I can save, view, and retrieve the data. I can view the data in the debugger. But I cannot cast back to int or an array.

```
foreach (object item in list)
{
    if (item.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        var arr = item as int[];

        foreach (var i in arr)
            print(i);
    }
}
```

At the if statement, item shows the data in the debugger pictured below but is false, but how do I cast back to object[]?

[image]

I have also tried:

```
var newItem = item as object[];
```

Edit: This is how I'm initializing the object. I start with an object because I get cast errors if I try wrapping an int[] when I send to the database.

```
var listValues = new List<object>();
var newArray   = new object[10];

newArray[0] = (int)c.Tag;
newArray[1] = (int)c.FPos;
newArray[2] = (int)c.ToL;

listValues.Add(newArray);
```

Comment: Could you execute list.GetType() and item.GetType() in debugger and tell us which types they really are?

Comment: It has a Count property, so you know it is not an array.  It is a collection type, all of them implement IEnumerable.

Comment: @HansPassant: You know it's not an array, because the type name starts with `System.Collections.Generic` (although `neric` and the actual class name is outside the visible area of the watch window)

Comment: @Dominik item Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]        
 list Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]

Answer (score 2):

A *cast* is (usually) different from a *conversion*. Most of the time when you're casting things in C#, you assume those things are already what you say they are, and you're not changing them at all. There is an exception for value types like `int` that get "boxed" and "unboxed" when you cast them to and from `object`. However, that exception does not extend to casting an `object[]` into an `int[]`.

An `int[]` is not the same thing as an `object[]`, so you can't just *cast* it as one. Instead, you have to produce a new array (or Collection, or IEnumerable, or whatever) that consists of all of those `object`s unboxed into ints. One way to do this is to use the `Cast<>()` extension method from the System.Linq namespace.

```
int[] arr = ((object[])item).Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Or, as a more complete example:

```
List<object[]> list = new List<object[]> { new object[] { 1, 2 }, new object[] { 3, 4 } };
foreach (object[] item in list)
{
    if (item.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        var arr = item.Cast<int>();
        foreach (var i in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

Based on your updated question, chances are that the real solution to your problem will go way beyond the scope of the original question. I don't know what mechanism you're using to store this and retrieve it from the database, but if you're using something like Entity Framework you probably need to change your model so that its values are strongly typed. In fact, the way you're taking properties off of an object and putting them into the database as an array is a big code smell: most likely your data model should be flattened into a type with named properties.

But to answer the simplest, most basic part of the question: you've got to cast your objects to the type that they actually *are* before trying to convert them. If you've got a `List<object>`, then use that:

```
foreach (List<object> item in list)
{
    int[] arr = item.Cast<int>().ToArray();
    foreach (var i in arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. In your example `item` is has a type of `object[]`, mine has a type of `object` when it comes back from the database. I edited my original question to add how I initialize the ` List<object>` before it goes to the database.

Answer (score 1):

After selecting your items from the DB you don't get a real `array`. Instead you get a `List` which cannot simply be cast to an array type. Thus `item.GetType().IsArray` is also false because it's a `List`

Try the following:

```
foreach (object item in list)
{
       IEnumerable<object> itemAsObjectEnumerable = (IEnumerable<object>)item;
       IEnumerable<int> itemAsIntEnumerable = itemAsObjectEnumerable.Cast<int>();
       foreach (var i in itemAsIntEnumerable)
       {
            print(i);
       }
}
```